# regex next pattern number = previous pattern number + 1

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying create a regex pattern to check a string containing two years spearated by '-' where year B = year A + 1 and these  dates are between 2000 and 2099 (date starting by 20)

For now I have a regex expression like this `/^20[0-9]{2}-20[0-9]{2}$ it's/g` but i don't know how to add a rule like "year B = year A - 1"

I would like to have these results when I do a preg_match :

```
2009-2010 -> true
2019-2020 -> true
2020-2021 -> true

1999-2000 -> false
2001-2099 -> false
2013-2020 -> false
2099-2100 -> false
2000-2100 -> false
```

Comment: Do it programmatically after getting a match.  Capture the two numbers, subtract and check. Regex is not capable of doing match when matching in PHP (you can't use code blocks as in Perl or Raku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do math using a regex

You could capture the 2 numbers with 2 capture groups. Using php, you can check if the values are between the thresholds of 2000 and 2099 and check if the first value plus one equals the second one.

```
$strings = [
    "2009-2010",
    "2019-2020",
    "2020-2021",
    "1999-2000",
    "2001-2099",
    "2013-2020",
    "2099-2100",
    "2000-2100"
];

$pattern  = "/^(20\d\d)-(20\d\d)/";
foreach ($strings as $str){
    if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $match)) {
        if (intval($match[1]) + 1 === intval($match[2])) {
            echo "$str is correct". PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
2009-2010 is correct
2019-2020 is correct
2020-2021 is correct
```